# openlayers 3 featureKey exists in featureChangeKeys

Tags: openlayers-3

I have an `ol.interaction.Select` acting on an `ol.source.Vector` which is within an `ol.layer.Vector`.  I can select and unselect individual countries fine.  I am using a dragbox to select multiple countries.  If I select anywhere outside of the multiply selected countries, the currently selected get unselected.  Excellent!

However, the problem is that if I select a currently selected country within the multiple, I get the **AssertionError: Assertion failed: featureKey exists in featureChangeKeys**

Here's my Vector layer:

```
_countrySelectSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'vendor/openlayers/geojson/countries.json',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});

var countryLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Country Select',
    visible: true,
    type: 'interactive-layers',
    source: _countrySelectSource
});
```

I add countryLayer to my map, `_map`.

I then create a _CountrySelect object that allows me to setActive(true|false) on the interactions related to my country selection.

```
_CountrySelect = {
    init : function(){
        this.select = new ol.interaction.Select();
        _map.addInteraction(this.select);

        this.dragbox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
            condition: ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly
        });
        _map.addInteraction(this.dragbox);

        this.setEvents();
    },
    setEvents: function(){
        var selectedFeatures = this.select.getFeatures();

        var infoBox = document.getElementById('info');
        var selfDragbox = this.dragbox;
        selfDragbox.on('boxend', function() {
            // features that intersect the box are added to the collection of
            // selected features, and their names are displayed in the "info"
            // div
            var extent = selfDragbox.getGeometry().getExtent();
            _countrySelectSource.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extent, function(feature) {
                selectedFeatures.push(feature);
                _countryCodes.push(feature.getId());
            });

            infoBox.innerHTML = _countryCodes.join(', ');

        });

        // clear selection when drawing a new box and when clicking on the map
        selfDragbox.on('boxstart', function() {
            selectedFeatures.clear();
            infoBox.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        });

        _map.on('singleclick', function(event) {
            selectedFeatures.clear();
            _countryCodes = [];

            _map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel,function(feature){
                selectedFeatures.push(feature);
                var id = feature.getId();
                var index = _countryCodes.indexOf(id);
                if ( index === -1 ) {
                    _countryCodes.push(feature.getId());
                }
            });

            infoBox.innerHTML = _countryCodes.join(', ');
        });
    },
    setActive: function(active){
        this.select.setActive(active);
        this.dragbox.setActive(active);
    }
};
_CountrySelect.init();
```

I am not sure if this is an issue with OL3 or my code.  Maybe there's an event I'm not handling?  Maybe it's the ol.interaction.DragBox (no luck researching on the DragBox).  Let me know what further information I can provide.

Comment: See [this ticket](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5248) if it helps somehow.

Comment: @JonatasWalker, I found this in the google search for this type of AssertionError as well.  However, I don't think my issue is the same.  At least, I can't seem to gleam anything from that issue.

Comment: @westandy Were you able to fix this problem ?  I'm currently facing this king of problem too and can't find any help on the internet...

Comment: Nevermind, I found my problem: I had 2 times the same id in my features list.

Comment: @Shimrod - I still haven't found a solution to this problem.  If you think your solution fixes this, please write it up.

Comment: unfortunatly, it was not directly related.  I modified my database values (oracle spatial values) by hand, and used 2 times the same Id, which caused the problem.